# blueman vs network manager

Tags: lubuntu, network-manager, lxde, lxpanel, blueman

Flavor: Lubuntu 16.04

At first: I am aware that there are numerous questions concerning a missing nm-applet icon in a lubuntu/lxde panel, but my case differs and I could not find one of the solutions to be applicable.

On startup, the nm-applet icon correctly shows up in the panel, but when I start the Bluetooth Manager from the Preferences, the nm-applet icon is **replaced/overlapped** by the blueman-applet icon. When I terminate the blueman-applet process, the nm-applet icon shows up again.

Of course I would like to have both icons side by side in the panel, not just one of them at a time – how can this be done?

Comment: A workaround could be to just kill blueman-applet after every use – the bluetooth connection seems not to be affected by this at all. Of course this is a rather intricate way.